# How to Find the Main Topic of a Body of Text

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, nltk

I know that in NLP it is a challenge to determine the topic of a sentence or possibly a paragraph. However, I am trying to determine what the title may be for something like a Wikipedia article (of course without using other methods). My only though is finding the most frequent words. For the article on New York City these were the top results:

```
[('new', 429), ('city', 380), ('york', 361), ("'s", 177), ('manhattan', 90), ('world', 84), ('united', 78), ('states', 74), ('===', 70), ('island', 68), ('largest', 66), ('park', 64), ('also', 56), ('area', 52), ('american', 49)]
```

From this I can see some sort of statistical significance is the sharp drop from 361 to 177. Regardless, I am neither a statistics or NLP expert (in fact I'm a complete noob at both) so **is this a viable way of determining the topic of a longer body of text. If so, what math am I looking for to calculate this? If not is there some other way in NLP to determine the topic or title for a larger body of text?** For reference, I am using nltk and Python 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have enough data and would like to have topics for a larger body of text like paragraph or an article you can use Topic Modelling methods like [LDA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latent_Dirichlet_allocation).

[Gensim](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/) has a easy to use implementation of LDA.

Comment: Can you please provide a link to a tutorial or elaborate more yourself.

Comment: This a step by step tutorial by [gensim](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/wiki.html)  

if you are more interested about the way LDA works internally you can check [this](https://www.cs.princeton.edu/~blei/kdd-tutorial.pdf)

Comment: and what if I don't have enough data? if I want to extract the topic based on one sentence, what should I do please?

Comment: Then your best bet is to do parsing and extract all noun phrases. You can use spacy (https://spacy.io/)  and get `noun_chunks` from the sentence. see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33289820/noun-phrases-with-spacy

Comment: I am using Agglomerative clustering to cluster news headlines
Once I get the clusters, I am looking to find the topic of a particular cluster
These are only 10-15 sentences on around same topic
Please suggest me a way to find the topics in such scenario

Answer (score 5):

You might consider use below algorithms. These are keyword extracting algorithms

[TF-IDF](http://www.tfidf.com/)

[TextRank](https://web.eecs.umich.edu/~mihalcea/papers/mihalcea.emnlp04.pdf)

[Here](https://yasserebrahim.wordpress.com/2012/10/25/tf-idf-with-pythons-nltk/) is a tutorial get you start on using TF-IDF in ntlk

Comment: Huh? You do the extraction *before* you use these methods.