# mergnig POS tag by noun phrase chunk

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

My question is similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33289820/noun-phrases-with-spacy). In `spacy`, I can do part-of-speech tagging and noun phrase identification separately e.g.

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en')
sentence = 'For instance , consider one simple phenomena : 
            a question is typically followed by an answer , 
            or some explicit statement of an inability or refusal to answer .'
token = nlp(sentence)
token_tag = [(word.text, word.pos_) for word in token]
```

Output looks like:

```
[('For', 'ADP'),
 ('instance', 'NOUN'),
 (',', 'PUNCT'),
 ('consider', 'VERB'),
 ('one', 'NUM'),
 ('simple', 'ADJ'),
 ('phenomena', 'NOUN'), 
 ...]
```

For Noun phrase or chunk, I can get `noun_chunks` which is a chunk of words as follows:

```
[nc for nc in token.noun_chunks] # [instance, one simple phenomena, an answer, ...]
```

I'm wondering if there is a way to cluster the POS tag based on `noun_chunks` so that I get the output as

```
[('For', 'ADP'),
 ('instance', 'NOUN'), # or NOUN_CHUNKS
 (',', 'PUNCT'),
 ('one simple phenomena', 'NOUN_CHUNKS'), 
 ...]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out how to do it. Basically, we can get start and end position of the noun phrase token as follows:

```
noun_phrase_position = [(s.start, s.end) for s in token.noun_chunks]
noun_phrase_text = dict([(s.start, s.text) for s in token.noun_chunks])
token_pos = [(i, t.text, t.pos_) for i, t in enumerate(token)]
```

Then I combine with this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43550219/merge-elements-in-list-based-on-given-indices/43550622#43550622) in order to merge list of `token_pos` based on `start`, `stop` position

```
result = []
for start, end in noun_phrase_position:
    result += token_pos[index:start]
    result.append(token_pos[start:end])
    index = end

result_merge = []
for i, r in enumerate(result):
    if len(r) > 0 and isinstance(r, list):
        result_merge.append((r[0][0], noun_phrase_text.get(r[0][0]), 'NOUN_PHRASE'))
    else:
        result_merge.append(r)
```

**Output**

```
[(1, 'instance', 'NOUN_PHRASE'),
 (2, ',', 'PUNCT'),
 (3, 'consider', 'VERB'),
 (4, 'one simple phenomena', 'NOUN_PHRASE'),
 (7, ':', 'PUNCT'),
 (8, 'a', 'DET'), ...
```