# Merge elements in list based on given indices

Tags: python, list

I want to merge element in the list based on given start and stop index of tuple (non-overlap for tuple). I'll leave the indices that don't mention as it is. This is my example

```
ls = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7']
merge = [(1, 3), (5, 7)]
```

Here, I want to merge index from `[1:3]` together and `[5:7]` together so the output should look something like following

```
['1', '23', '4', '5', '67']
```

I tried to loop using `range(len(ls))` but it doesn't seem to be the right way to tackle this problem. Let me know if someone has simple way to solve this problem.

Comment: Are the merge tuples guaranteed to not overlap? Are they guaranteed to be in any ordering?

Comment: `ls[5:7] --> ['6', '7']`, did you make a typo?

Comment: Yeah, no overlap! I'll fix the question right now. Also, I did make a typo.

Comment: What about ordering of the tuples in `merge`? See my comment on Vadim's solution below.

Comment: It would be best if we can consider any ordering. However, i can sort the the `merge` by start position before hand in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short "trick" with reversed `merge` list:

```
ls = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7']
merge = [(1, 3), (5, 7)]

for t in merge[::-1]:
    merged = ''.join(ls[t[0]:t[1]])  # merging values within a range
    ls[t[0]:t[1]] = [merged]         # slice replacement

print(ls)
```

The output:

```
['1', '23', '4', '5', '67']
```

Comment: This solution has the added benefit that it requires no ordering of the tuples in the `merge` list to work correctly.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest, thanks Roman. Both solutions (from you and Vadim) are great. It just opens my way of solving this kind of problem :)

Answer (score 7):

A quick-and-dirty solution would be:

```
ls = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7']
merge = [(1, 3), (5, 7)]

result = []
index = 0

for start, end in merge:
    result += ls[index:start]
    result.append("".join(ls[start:end]))
    index = end

print result # ['1', '23', '4', '5', '67']
```

Comment: Ah, yes, this is certainly a reasonable solution, especially compared to the monstrosity I had posted originally.

Comment: This solution only works if `merge` is ordered and there are no overlaps. (Consider two such examples: `merge = [(5,7),(1,3)]` and `merge = [(1,3),(2,4)]`). I asked a question about this on the OP.

Comment: Thanks @Vadim! I can't accept both solution at once so I gave you thumbs up instead!

Comment: No worries, the other solution is definitely nice. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

For the fun of it, because I've been learning Haskell, a recursive solution:

```
def recursive(ls, merge):
    if merge == []:
        return ls
    else:
        x, xs = merge[0], merge[1:]
        return ls[:x[0]] + [''.join(ls[x[0]:x[1]])] + recursive(ls, xs)[x[1]:]
```

Only works if there are no overlapping intervals, however.